# Why (and how) ASP.NET Cache gets stored in Unmanaged Memory?

Tags: asp.net, caching, memory, heap-memory, unmanaged-memory

OK, all you ASP.NET Experts: I have used reflector to look into ASP.NET Cache implementation (which sits on `HttpRuntime.Cache` and `HttpContext.Current.Cache`) uses a `Hashtable` internally to keep the cache.

However, the data gets stored in unmanaged memory. This is very strange since I could not see anywhere data getting stored in unmanaged memory. However, writing a very simple web application that inserts a chunk of byte array into cache, we can see this:

[image]

- Private Bytes: 460MB
- Bytes in all heaps: 150MB

### =>

## Managed Memory: 150 MB

## Unmanaged Memory: 310 MB

So basically I am calling the application many times (each increase is 1000x requests each putting 64KB empty buffer *byte[]* into cache). So the one that has grown the most is **private bytes** (total memory) instead of **bytes in all heaps** (managed memory). However *I am expecting managed memory to grow in line with total memory* since I am adding objects to the managed heap using Hashtable.

Can you please explain this behaviour?

---

## UPDATE

As Simon said, the bytes in all heaps value only changes after a garbage collection - I changed the code to induce garbage collection and it update the counters. Increase in Gen 2 Heap memory is EXACTLY the same as the amount of memory added. However, unmanaged memory is still much higher. In this example, Heap 2 was only 96MB while total memory 231 MB.

[image]

Comment: What datatypes are you caching? byte[] arrays? System.Drawing objects? Some .NET types do exist in unmanaged space, but we don't know what ones you're using.

Comment: could you post your code: how do you insert data in the cache, how do you garbage collect them, your cache config. Also a memory dump would be very usefull

Comment: Looks like it's a mistake to declare "Private bytes" === "Unmanaged memory". It's a windows process memory. And .net heap is allocated from it, that's why private bytes grow.

Comment: @mikalai private bytes = managed + unmanaged memory

Comment: First, only change values should correlate (if you add X data to managerd, you'll have Y addition to unmanaged memory). You provided only absolute. Could you track difference? Second - both .net runtime and worker process routines can use unmanaged heaps behind the scene freely, so you can't really say what's there and why. Third - .net memory is relatively small, so you just ran the process. Try to put it under long-running load test and the picture would be different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `# Bytes in all Heaps` is only updated when the garbage collection is executed, while the `Private Bytes` is available at much faster update rate. (I'm not sure where that number comes from, internally, and how often it's updated.)

The amount of `Private Bytes` increases just after 17:42:45. This amount does seem to match the value jump of `# Bytes in all Heaps` at about 17:43:10. It looks like it took 20-25 seconds before any garbage collection was done and updated the `# Bytes in all Heaps`counter.

It's hard to work out how memory allocations work from a few minutes worth of performance counters presented in a screenshot. ;) Keep running your test and see how your expectations work out over a longer time period.

TL;DR: The amount of managed bytes should correlate with private bytes, but the managed counter will only update during a garbage collection.

---

*Small note from the OP: As this response says, the lagging in the memory can be fully explained by lagging GC. The fact that unmanaged memory also rises was not my question. So thanks @Simon.*